# Python regular expression: get result without the search string used

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file with data like this :

```
[AC 2 StartTime 3.29 s   32912KB -> 27720KB   24.54 ms]
[AC 3 StartTime 3.35 s   39404KB -> 36252KB   11.05 ms]
[AC 4 StartTime 3.55 s   44592KB -> 39316KB   1.91 ms]
```

I want to obtain the StartTime(s) in an array using regular expression. I tried using the script:

```
StartTime = re.findall(r"StartTime \d+\.\d+",text)
```

But, it gives *StartTime* string along with time. How can I just get the time(i.e. integers) without the string?

Result is **Start 3.29** but I want **just 3.29**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include a capture group (using parentheses) to select the part you want:

```
 StartTime = re.findall(r"StartTime (\d.\d.)", text)
                                  # ^ capture this part
```

but your regex seems odd - it gets a digit (`'\d'`) followed by *any character* (`'.'` - *not* a full stop) followed by a digit followed by any character. You may be better with:

```
StartTime = re.findall(r"StartTime (\d\.\d{2})", text)
```

which is a digit followed by a full stop (`'\.'` - note backslash to escape) followed by two digits.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """[AC 2 StartTime 3.29 s   32912KB -> 27720KB   24.54 ms]
[AC 3 StartTime 3.35 s   39404KB -> 36252KB   11.05 ms]
[AC 4 StartTime 3.55 s   44592KB -> 39316KB   1.91 ms]"""
>>> re.findall(r"StartTime (\d\.\d{2})", s)
['3.29', '3.35', '3.55']
```

Comment: How could I store the output as array of integers instead of arrays of strings?

Comment: `list(map(float,['3.29', '3.35', '3.55']))` will give you a list of floats.
`

Comment: ... or `[float(element) for element in lst]` also gives you the list of floats converted from the `lst` that is the list of strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a capturing group `( )` to extract the part you want. `findall` returns the captured groups.

```
>>> StartTime = re.findall(r'StartTime ([\d.]+)', text)
['3.29', '3.35', '3.55']
```

You can also use a **Positive Lookbehind** here.

```
>>> StartTime = re.findall(r'(?<=StartTime )[\d.]+', text)
['3.29', '3.35', '3.55']
```

**Note:** I used `[\d.]+` here, meaning any character of: digits (`0-9`), `.` (`1` or more times)